# R programming for time series

Tags: r

I am working on huge data file around millon of entires in excel and the format is something like this:
file contain data value at every second for a week

Timevalue   ;value

29.07.2015 20:57:20 ; 972.422

29.07.2015 20:57:21  ;972.402

I want to plot the time series for this data.
I have tried to use normal plot function and read.csv command but not getting proper result.
I also tried zoo package and with zoo i am getting this error

In zoo(rval3, ix) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique.
I used the unique function on my csv file still getting the same value.
Can some guide me how can i solve the task.

(PS: I am new to R)

Answer (score 0):

This will read in the data averaging rows having the same date/time.  Replace `text = Lines` with something like `file = "myfile"` :

```
Lines <- "Timevalue ;value
29.07.2015 20:57:20 ; 972.422
29.07.2015 20:57:21 ;972.402"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ";", aggregate = mean,
  format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%H", tz = "")

plot(z)
```

Also, note that the message you got was **not** an error message.  It was a warning message.

Comment: hello , Sorry for the late reply , I a currently changing my dataset, my data set contain duplicate entry and I want zoo to work with duplicates, is it possible? Or there is some other package i can use for multiple entry?

Comment: The xts package can handle duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

I would first check if the time column has a time format (like POSIXlt)
with str()
if it doesn't then convert it with something like this,
    as.POSIXlt(timesColumn, format = "%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M:%S")

And then you can try to plot it